# How to access public variable through a contract interface

Tags: solidity, remix

A contract I am trying to interact with has a public boolean variable isSold, but no getter function. I've been trying to access isSold using an interface, and the built in getting function isSold(). Why doesn't this work, and how would I be able to access a public variable from another contract?

**Contract I am trying to interact with.**

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Shop {
  uint public price = 100;
  bool public isSold;

  function buy() public {
    isSold = true;
  }
}
```

**My Code**

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

interface Shop {
    function buy() external;
    function isSold() external returns (bool);
}

contract CheapBuyer {

  Shop cheapShop = Shop(0x562935467272EEBeEBeF4D9502284AF6C062e5Dd);

  function tryBuy() public {
      if (!cheapShop.isSold()) {
          cheapShop.buy();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, what error you do you exactly ? Double check the address `0x562935467272EEBeEBeF4D9502284AF6C062e5Dd` maybe you have an issue here ?

Comment: I have the same issue,  not sure why its not working

Answer (score 0):

It should work just fine.

I modified your example just a little bit and tried in Remix. I deployed `CheapBuyer` contract and executed the function successfully.

Here's my modified version:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.1;

contract Shop {
  uint public price = 100;
  bool public isSold;

  function buy() public {
    isSold = true;
  }
}

interface IShop {
  function buy() external;
  function isSold() external returns (bool);
}

contract CheapBuyer {

  Shop cheapShop = new Shop();

  function tryBuy() public {
    IShop other = IShop(address(cheapShop));
    if (!other.isSold()) {
        other.buy();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You also need to specify "override" keyword to state variable in Shop Contract. If not, you get an error: TypeError: Overriding public state variable is missing "override" specifier.

Comment: Hmm. There is no inheritance here, so nothing can be overridden.

Comment: That's what compiler says when you implement IShop in Shop contract.

Comment: I have provided the full code in a new answer because here I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing this example in Remix, so I implemented the example, importing the interface in IShop.sol file

**Interface (IShop.sol)**

```
pragma solidity 0.8.1;

interface IShop {
  function buy() external;
  function isSold() external returns (bool);
}
```

**Implementation (Shop.sol)**

```
pragma solidity 0.8.1;

import "./IShop.sol";

contract Shop is IShop {
  uint public price = 100;
  bool public override isSold;

  function buy() public override {
    isSold = true;
  }
}
```

**Contract (CheapBuyer.sol)**

```
pragma solidity 0.8.1;

import "./Shop.sol";

contract CheapBuyer {

  Shop cheapShop = new Shop();

  function tryBuy() public {
    IShop other = IShop(address(cheapShop));
    if (!other.isSold()) {
        other.buy();
    }
  }
}
```

If you do not specify `override` keyword in `isSold` state variable, you get the following error:

> TypeError: Overriding public state variable is missing "override"
> specifier.  --> contracts/Interface_pruebas/Shop.sol:7:3:

Answer (score 0):

exactly should be marked function with "Override" because to implement interfaces you need this "override" on your functions.